# Proof by induction with inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

Let $x_1 = 1$ and $x_{n+1}$ = $\sqrt{{x_n}^2 + \frac{1}{(x_n)^2}}$

Prove by mathematical induction that for all $n ≥ 1,   1 ≤ x_n ≤ \sqrt n$

I have done induction proofs before, but not with an inequality. I know I need to start off by showing $P(1)$:

$x_1 = 1$ and $1≤1≤\sqrt 2$ Is this the right first step? Where do I go from here? My instinct is to change every $x$ to $(x+1).$

Comment: No, the first step is to question the assertion that $1 \leq x_1 \leq \sqrt{n}$, with $n$ set to $1$.  The next step is to prove that if the assertion is true for $n=N$, then this implies both of the following: (1) $1 \leq x_{(N+1)}$ and (2) $x_{(N+1)} \leq \sqrt{N+1}.$

Comment: If you have trouble solving the problem re the previous note, please edit your query to **show your work.**

Comment: Hint: If $1 \leq x_n \leq \sqrt{n}$, $x_n^2 \leq n$ and $x_n^{-2} \leq 1$.